# How to color based on b-factor for all the frames in one object in Pymol?

Tags: pymol

I load a `protein.pdb` file into `Pymol`. This file has multiple frames (or states), and with different b-factor values at different frames at the `PDB` file `b-factor` columns.

[image]

After running the `spectrum b` [command](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Spectrum), the colouring is only based on the last state of the object.

So can I colour the frames differently using their corresponding `b-factor` values? In that case, I can see the colour changing throughout the frame playing.

In case someone wants to create a PDB of multiple frames, you can do like this:

```
MODEL        1
ATOM ......
ATOM ......
ENDMDL
MODEL        2
ATOM ......
ATOM ......
ENDMDL
```

Comment: Do you have a PDB ID one could use to reproduce this?

Comment: The PDB downloaded from the PDB website usually has only one frame. But my PDB comes from molecular dynamics, which has multiple frames. You can simply add a line of "MODEL        1" before the content, then add another line of "ENDMDL" at the end, and repeat this multiple times to create a PDB with multiple frames